# Laravel adding WHERE to DB::raw and Joins

Tags: mysql, laravel

Here is my code:

```
return ExportInvoice::join('sold_products', 'sold_products.export_invoice_id', '=', 'export_invoices.id')
        ->join('products', 'sold_products.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->select(
            'sold_products.product_id',
            'products.name',
            DB::raw('
                round(round(sum(round(sold_products.sold_price * sold_products.quantity * (1 - sold_products.discount / 100), 2))
                 * (1 - export_invoices.discount / 100), 2) * (1 + IF(export_invoices.tax, 14, 0) / 100), 2)
                 as total
            ')
        )
        ->groupBy('sold_products.product_id', 'products.name', 'export_invoices.discount', 'export_invoices.tax')
        ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
        ->limit(100)
        ->get();
```

## What I am trying to do:

I am trying to add `whereNotNull('export_invoices.deleted_at')` and `whereNotNull('sold_products.deleted_at')` because I am using Laravel soft delete and the above query return all data even those who are soft-deleted.

Comment: how have you attempted to add these conditions?

Comment: "I am trying to add ..." - And what stops you to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to do just `->whereNull('sold_products.deleted_at')` and `->whereNull('export_invoices.deleted_at')` then try to add this after `select` statement.

```
$columns = ['sold_products.deleted_at', 'export_invoices.deleted_at']

->where(function($q) use ($columns){
    foreach($columns as $column){
        $q->whereNull($columns);
    }
})
```

So it would be:

```
$columns = ['sold_products.deleted_at', 'export_invoices.deleted_at']

return ExportInvoice::join('sold_products', 'sold_products.export_invoice_id', '=', 'export_invoices.id')
        ->join('products', 'sold_products.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->select(
            'sold_products.product_id',
            'products.name',
            DB::raw('
                round(round(sum(round(sold_products.sold_price * sold_products.quantity * (1 - sold_products.discount / 100), 2))
                 * (1 - export_invoices.discount / 100), 2) * (1 + IF(export_invoices.tax, 14, 0) / 100), 2)
                 as total
            ')
        )->where(function($q) use ($columns){
           foreach($columns as $column){
             $q->whereNull($columns);
           }
})->groupBy('sold_products.product_id', 'products.name', 'export_invoices.discount', 'export_invoices.tax')
        ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
        ->limit(100)
        ->get();
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: The problem is that it wont return the product if it has one deleted_by row

Comment: Even if you use `orWhereNotNull ` instead of `whereNotNull`?

Comment: Yes.. It wont return the product itself if it has deleted_at in invoices or sold products

Comment: Please try to add `->withTrashed` 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models

Comment: Problem is that the where clause work on the joins so if where failed it wont join the product

Comment: It works but it should be `whereNull($column)` because I should return the NOT deleted columns. Please edit your answer so I could accept it. And thanks for your time and effort

Comment: Thank you @Jaad for getting back to me on this. 

I edited my answer. I hope this is good. Thanks for coordinating accept on this. 

Thank you.